# How to transfer a built Cython extension from a PC to another?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a PC in which I can not run setup.py file when I build a cython extension, because I do not have admin rights to install VC++ 14.0 (for python 3). So I decided to build the cython extension on another PC which works great. Now I want to transfer the cython module (for example helloword) to the other PC.

I tried to copied all the files generated after running setup.py, but it doesn't recognize the the modul with the following message:

[image]

I use python 3.7.3 to build the cython extension then copied all the files to python 3.6.1. Both PC are on windows. I use pycharm 2019 on both windows.

The structure of my project looks like below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognizing" the module? What is the error message? And also you must be more precise concerning your Python versions, i.e. at least a digit more. Also what operating systems do both PCs have?

Comment: dont forget that if you dont install the module you either have to add it to you `PATH` or run your script from that dir

Comment: @ead I updated my question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @Nullman: I sucessed to import other python file using import from the dir, not the cython extension.

Comment: I bet i know what it is. your compiled file is trying to use something, like a dll that you dont have on this machine or have it in a different place, I've ran into this issue myself. you can use dependency walker and procmon both from [sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) to see where its failing

Comment: @Nullman: could you explain the details? it's the first time I heard about sysinternals, I really don't know how to use it, it looks like another planet for me.

Comment: i cannot give you a tutorial right now, but what you will want to do is start procmon, then start your script, then hit the stop button in procmon and filter the output to only see python. read the lines and you will probably see that its failing to find a file. alternatively, run dependency walker and load your compiled file, it should show you what its trying to load, and will mark files it cant find. good luck and may the odds be ever in your favour

Comment: Basically you cannot/should not run extensions from CPython3.X on CPython3.Y.  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147. You should build them with the right Python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentionned in the commentaries, you cannot run a compiled cython for 3.7 in a 3.6 version (At least for windows). Also, the architecture should be exactly the same aswell (You cannot compile on a 32bits machine, and deploy it on a 64bits machine)

Once you solved all the dependency problem, you should run the `python setup.py bdist_wheel` command to create the wheel, and then run a `pip install <path_to_wheel>`

Comment: Do you know all the constraints? I have problems, but I don't know if because compiling on Ubuntu 20.04 and running on 18.04, or because compiling with Python 3.6.X and running on Python 3.6.Y.